# Convert float to decimal with parameterized precision

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

How to Use Something like this: ?

```
Convert(Decimal(15,@DecimalPlace),table.column) AS XYZ
```

I want to convert a float value to decimal where the precision is passed as an external parameter

Comment: Which DBMS are you using(PostgreSQL, MySQl, MS SQL ...) and did you check the documentation whether there is some cast function set available?

Comment: Sorry For Incomplete Info..I am usin SQL Server 2008R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd have to use dynamic sql for this:

```
DECLARE @DecimalPlace INT = 4
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT Convert(Decimal(15,' + CAST(@DecimalPlace AS NVARCHAR) + '),table.column) AS XYZ FROM table'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b65d3/1/0)